# steam wont open?

Tags: steam

when i open steam it says "steam could not connect to servers" Last time this happened i just installed it and then re-installed it. It said i had to re-install all  my games but it did save my achievements ... This time i have had the same problem but when i re-install it it doesn't work. I think it is something to do with far cry as it.

My Conclusion is tat i cant open steam at all i was wondering if you might h sve the answer or u have faced a similar problem!

Comment: Did you try launching Steam with the `-tcp` argument?

Comment: what do u mean @oldmud0

Comment: `Windows key`+`R` (`Run...`), then type in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -tcp`.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I had this issue earlier today. You type in thr entire path for steam and and put -tcp at the end with no quotation marks. It should remedy the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have too that Steam is unable to connect no matter what, but so far I've always been able to fix it by removing the `appcache` folder from `program files -> steam`, making sure no processes are running (kill them if they do) and reboot steam.

For me this has always fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont understand

Comment: ?? i am new to windows 8 please simplify

Comment: @yourmum101 go to the location where steam is installed, default it will be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam` and there delete the `appcache` folder. If you don't know how to kill the steam processes, either make sure you dont start Steam before deleting the folder, or reboot your pc after deleting and then start steam.